Prime Ideals of $\Bbb Z[x]$ containing $\mathbb(3, x^2+3x+5)$
I need to find the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3, x^2+3x+5) \cong  \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+3x+5) \cong \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+2)$.
Therefore, we have that $(x+2)$ and $(x+1)$ are the two maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ containing $(x^2+3x+5)$.
How do I get back the required ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?
What map is to be used to get the answer?
A similar question was asked here. However, it did not answer my question on how to get back the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

The "required ideals" in $\Bbb Z[x]$ are $\pi^{-1}((x-\varepsilon))=(x-\varepsilon,3)$ ($\epsilon=\pm1$).

$(3,x+1)$ and $(3,x+2)$

Please don't answer questions in the comments! These are great answers, even if brief, but the question remains open because it has no answers.

Thank you, Anne. The ideal correspondence answered my question.
